# How to create SQL Database, tables and storage procedures in Basic MSI Project creating in InstallShield 2016 Pemier?

Tags: c#, sql-server, installshield, prerequisites

I work with InstallShield first time. I develop, in InstallShield 2016 Premier (21-days trial version), installation package (Basic MSI Project) to install my application on customer's computer. My application works with MS SQL Server 2014 Express local DB, so I included prerequisite of Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Expres Local DB(x64) in my setup project. Please see below:

[image]

If I understand correctly, when customer is double-clicking on 'setup.exe' file name then installation of SQL Server starts. After SQL Server's installation completion, the installation of my application itself begins. During the installation of my application CREATE DATABASE SQL-statement must execute one time (for creating of 'My_DB' database on the MS SQL Server instaled). After it, CREATE TABLE SQL-statement must execute two times (for creating of two tables in 'My_DB' database) and CREATE PROCEDURE SQL-statement must execute seven times (for creating of seven storage procedures in 'My_DB' database). But I don't know two things: 1) How can I know the name of the SQL Server after installation of Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Expres Local DB(x64) prerequisite? 2) Should I use SQL Scripts view in my Basic MSI Project to set CREATE DATABASE, CREATE TABLE and CREATE PROCEDURE operators? Please help me.

Comment: You can probably find out how to do this at the InstallShield web site. Have you looked there?

Comment: Thanks, I had looked there before I wrote to here.